# error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
    1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

```
4   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In my app.component the line

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In my package.json

```
{
  "name": "auth-table2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "firebase": "^7.9.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

In app.module.ts

```
import { AdminAuthGuard } from './admin-auth-guard.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database'; 
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth'; 
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BsNavbarComponent } from './bs-navbar/bs-navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component';
import { CheckOutComponent } from './check-out/check-out.component';
import { OrderSuccessComponent } from './order-success/order-success.component';
import { MyOrdersComponent } from './my-orders/my-orders.component';
import { AdminProductsComponent } from './admin/admin-products/admin-products.component';
import { AdminOrdersComponent } from './admin/admin-orders/admin-orders.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BsNavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent,
    CheckOutComponent,
    OrderSuccessComponent,
    MyOrdersComponent,
    AdminProductsComponent,
    AdminOrdersComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    // NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterTestingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
      { path: 'shopping-cart', component: ShoppingCartComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

      { path: 'check-out', component: CheckOutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'order-success', component: OrderSuccessComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'my/orders', component: MyOrdersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

      { 
        path: 'admin/products', 
        component: AdminProductsComponent, 
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard] 
      },
      { 
        path: 'admin/orders', 
        component: AdminOrdersComponent, 
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard] 
      }
    ])    
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    AdminAuthGuard,
    UserService
  ],
  exports: [
    [ RouterModule ]
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You should not have `RouterTestingModule` in real modules. It's only for unit tests' `TestBed` modules.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are using `RouterTestingModule` this is only use for unit try to use `RouterModule`

Like this

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I was trying to import a Module which would declare a specific set of components. One of those components had a `<router-outlet>` tag.
This was the error during the compilation:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/layout/layout.component.html:8:17 - error NG8001: 'router-oulet' is not a known element:
    1. If 'router-oulet' is an Angular component, then verify that 
it is part of this module.
    2. If 'router-oulet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

    8                 <router-oulet></router-oulet>
```

What I did was to import **RouterModule** on the external module, like this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        AlertsComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        LogoutComponent,
        MessageComponent,
        SearchComponent,
        SidebarComponent,
        TopbarComponent,
        UserInfoComponent,
        LayoutComponent,
    ],
    imports:[
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class LayoutModule {}
```

then I imported the module on the **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    LayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Now it's working**

Answer (score 1):

Angular version - `10.1.5`

*app.component.html*

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Error -

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

**Solution -**

*app.module.ts*

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [..., RouterModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

error `NG 8001`, and others just like it are caused by **improper** import statements.

The modules are always found within the **first folder** of the component area.

only use the `RouterModule` in `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';`

Answer (score 0):

That error happens at ng-build, or ng-serve time when changes are made to things like the import statements, or when adding new modules. The message is trying to tell us that it can't find this component. This link probably be very usefull:

[https://dev.to/jwp/material-components-4616#:~:text=The%20NG8001%20Error%20happens%20at,and%20how%20to%20fix%20them.](https://dev.to/jwp/material-components-4616#:%7E:text=The%20NG8001%20Error%20happens%20at,and%20how%20to%20fix%20them.)

In my case the error was that i created a new Module, and did not include the asociated component in the `declarations:[]` section of the module:

inside the AlxModule (in my case), did not declare AlxComponent...
so in the moment a i did it like below, just worked fine for me:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AlxComponent, HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    AlxRoutingModule,    
  ],
})
export class AlxModule { }
```